# Sublime Text build system generates [WinError 6] The handle is invalid error

Tags: powershell, sublimetext, windows-7-x64, ruby-1.9.3, asciidoctor

I'm attempting to create a [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/) build system to render and Asciidoc-formatted document using [AsciiDoctor](http://asciidoctor.org/).

AsciiDoc.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["asciidoctor","$file"],
    "selector": "source.asciidoc"
}
```

When I execute the build <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>,  I get an error:

```
[WinError 6] The handle is invalid
[cmd: ['asciidoctor', 'C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Desktop\\hello\\hello.asc']]
[dir: C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\hello]
[path: c:\tools\ruby193\bin\asciidoctor]
[Finished]
```

I'm able to successfully render the document via the Windows Command Processor, the PowerShell, and the Ruby prompt.

This build script leads to the same error:

```
{
    "cmd": ["asciidoctor","$file"],
    "path": "c:\\tools\\ruby193\\bin\\asciidoctor",
    "shell": true,
    "selector": "source.asciidoc"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: [Build system: "The handle is invalid"](http://cc.bingj.com/cache.aspx?q=build%20system%20The%20handle%20is%20invalid&d=4845437494955815&mkt=en-US&setlang=en-US&w=a0Rl1KiolUebc1sk_dkpv5y0vMIxF2Jo).

The final response:

> > by showka on Sun Oct 02, 2011 7:34 pm 
> >     Thank you very much, launching Sublime Text outside of the command prompt gets rid of this problem.
> >
> > I've tried setting `PYTHONPATH` to run from the prompt but that won't fix it. My command prompt has so much goo in the environment
> >     variables I'm sure something else is tripping it up as well. :) For
> >     now I'll just make a second batch file to launch Sublime with certain
> >     programs added to the path.
>
> ...
>
> UPDATE: I found the issue and can now run it from my command prompt.
>
> Here's how my batch file used to look:
>
> Code: Select all
>       `SET PYTHONPATH=START "Sublime Text 2" /B "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" %*`
>
> The /B option was messing it up for some reason. Normally I need that
>   to keep the command prompt from waiting for the launched program to
>   exit, but with Sublime its unnecessary for some reason. Taking the
>   option off made it work.